# How do you upgrade pip from v8.1.2 to v9.0.0?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, pip, upgrade, macos-sierra

I have issues with regards to the upgrade from pip v8.1.2 to v9.0.0. I have read several other posts on previous upgrades but the solutions were not valid for my problem.

I have installed Python 3.6.0b2 (runs on macOS Sierra) and I cannot manage to upgrade pip anymore. 
When I run $ pip install --upgrade pip I get an Exception which points to /Library/Python/2.7 folders. 
When I run $ pip3 install --upgrade pip I get an Exception which points to /Library/Python/3.5 folders. 
Both time I get a message telling me to consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip'. How could I fix this ?

Many thanks in advance.